# i want install Keyboard Layout Editor on ubuntu 15.4 , but i get errors :(

Tags: python

when i want install Keyboard Layout Editor on ubuntu 15.5 i get some problem....
i followed this Installation guide:

[Keyboard Layout Editor](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor)

```
git clone https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor.git
cd keyboardlayouteditor/
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install http://www.antlr3.org/download/Python/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.2.tar.gz
wget http://www.antlr3.org/download/antlr-3.1.2.jar
java -classpath antlr-3.1.2.jar org.antlr.Tool *.g
```

but when I use this command :

```
sudo pip install http://www.antlr3.org/download/Python/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.2.tar.gz
```

I get this error:

[image]

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Temporary failure in name resolution" means your connection dropped. Try again over wired Internet, or on a different network.

Comment: my internet is 5mb speed :/ :(

Comment: Try again then!

Comment: i try it 100 time's -_-

Comment: I see two other possibilities: bad DNS, or the pip server is down. Try changing your DNS to 8.8.8.8.